# User settings (Default Recordtype) in Apex

Tags: apex, metadata-api

is it possible to find out in apex, if the user selected a recordtype as a default in the user settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users cannot select a default record type. The user can only choose to use the default record type by default (or not). The DescribeSobjectResult#getRecordTypeInfos (and related methods) return ways to get a hold of available record types, which includes a method RecordTypeInfo#isDefaultRecordTypeMapping, which specifies if the record type is the default for the user. As far as I can tell, there is no way to determine in Apex if the user has chosen to use the default record type by default.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this, that the user only choose the record type to be chosen.
Thanks for confirming this!